# Set git tag and checkout on Windows

Tags: git, build, tagging

We are in the process of changing revision control system from Starteam to Git and GitHub.com. With Starteam we use labels. A label is a named snapshot for example 3.14.1.3145. That is automatically built every morning. Next morning it is 3.14.1.3146. I believe git tag is the same as label ? We use Smartgit as client but from the build application we have to use git commandline.

I am a bit of a newbie on git and wonder the following.

1. How can I set a label in Git and store it on GitHub ?
2. How can I checkout all files for a specific label from GitHub and then build from that ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, tag is what you described. You can checkout it like a branch, and if you use checkout's -b option, it will create new local branch for you. If you only checkout without -b, git will warn you, that you are not on any branch, but it is not a problem as long as you do not commit anything.

You push tags to Github the same way as you push new branch: `git push origin tagname`

When creating tag name, take a look at 'git describe' command. It may help you.

To checkout and build:

```
git fetch origin && git checkout 3.14.1.314 --force && make
```

Btw, I have small, but good experience with Git Extensions on Windows. It has nice GUI, and it includes some basic shell with git.

Comment: +1, but The only true way to use git is the command line. Every other UI I’ve ever seen masks away important internals of git. If you stick to an UI, you will never really learn git and understand what’s going on.

Comment: Yeah, that's why Git Extensions shows commands when it runs them. I'm recommending Git Extensions becouse it is one of few GUIs which guide you and do not step in your way when it gets complicated. And since there is no really good terminal on Windows, it is probably the best option here.

Comment: You can just use the cygwin terminal with mintty – that’s a pretty good terminal :).